# Permanent redirect of page dependent on parameters

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to redircet www.mysite.com/abc/mypage.php?id=123 to www.mysite.com/newpage.htm

I've tried this in my .htaccess file but it doesn't work. (I just get a 404)

```
RedirectPermanent /abc/mypage\.php\?id=123 /newpage.htm
```

What is the correct syntax?

Answer (score 0):

No you cannot match QUERY_STRING using `Redirect` directive. You can use `mod_rewrite` instead:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+abc/mypage\.php\?id=123[&s] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /newpage.htm? [R=302,L]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
# do this once per htaccess
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^id=123$
# to redirect permanently
RewriteRule ^/?abc/mypage\.php$ /newpage.htm [R=301,L]
```

Remember that the `[R=302]` flag is used to redirect temporarily.